# Calculated fields based on values from two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two different tables called BB.BOATBKG and BK_BOOKING where BB_BOATBKG.BK.KEY  =BK_BOOKING.Z_ID .

I need to create a calculated field in BB.BOATBKG where the calculation ( booking lead time days) is basically

```
BB_BOATBKG.ORIG.DATE.EXT  - BK.BOOKING.BOOK.DATE.EXT
```

For this i have created a function called GetBookingLeadTimeDays.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Getbookingleadtimedays] (@ORIGDATE DATE, @BOOKDATE DATE)  
RETURNS INT   
AS  BEGIN  
RETURN ( DATEDIFF(day, @ORIGDATE, @BOOKDATE)  )  
END.
```

After creating the function,  that i created a calculated field in BB_BOATBKG as

```
ALTER TABLE  dbo.BB_BOATBKG ADD Calc_booking_lead_time_days  AS dbo.Getbookingleadtimedays ([ORIG_DATE_EXT],[dbo.BK_BOOKING.BOOK_DATE_EXT] )
```

But it is not working and came with error message Invalid column name 'dbo.BK_BOOKING.BOOK_DATE_EXT'

Anyone please help as i think i am finding difficult to create a calculated field based on values from two different table.

Comment: Add your schema for a better result..!

Comment: How is it meant to know which row from `BK_BOOKING` it's meant to use to obtain a value for `BOOK_DATE_EXT`? Consider not just your current case, but that *multiple* foreign keys can exist between any two tables. You can't do this as a computed column. Maybe consider a view?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use a `JOIN`.

You join them based on how they are related, can you elaborate?

You can, then, `SELECT` whatever calculation you like based on the combination in the two related tables.

Given your schema I can provide more detail.

Comment: SO should i use a join within the function? i created the function like as below

Comment: How are the two tables related?

Comment: SO should i use a join within the function? i created the function like as below 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Getbookingleadtimedays] (@ORIGDATE DATE, @BOOKDATE DATE)

Comment: In the above tables BK.BOOKING is the main booking table and BB.BOATBKG holds leg details  ( one booking in BK_BOOKING may have different legs in BB_BOATBKG),